# Do I have to add the mx records in both the domain and the hosting?

Tags: dns, hosting

If I'm using a 3rd party server for my emails, lets say G Suite, do I have to change the MX records in the domain as well as the hosting server? or pointing them in the domain will be enough?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure MX records at Name Server(s) which are authoritative for your domain name (and have your domain zone delegated to them by TLD name servers).

You can find which are those name servers in several ways, for example with command `dig ns example.com +short`, or by entering your domain name here https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/ (choose NS), and looking at "ANSWER" section in output.